# Octonionic Hopf bundle is a bundle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

> We have the octonionic Hopf map $f: S^{15} \to S^8$, where $f$ is a bundle of fiber $S^7$.

To me this is not obvious. How do I see that the octonionic Hopf bundle is indeed a bundle? Thanks.

Comment: To get a local trivialization, first find a local section of $S^{15} \to S^8$, and then use the "multiplication" $S^7 \times S^{15} \to S^{15}$ to move it around. The proof looks formally rather similar to the usual proof that $G \to G/H$ is a fiber bundle for $H$ a closed subgroup of a Lie group $G$.

Comment: Ehresmann's theorem is a sufficiently powered nuke.